# Custom Control Resource is adding new lines

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# ASP.Net custom control resource file that appears to be adding new lines before and after the value, despite not actually having any there.

The .ascx file has:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTeam" runat="server" Text="Team:" meta:resourcekey="lblTeamResource1"></asp:Label>
```

The .ascx.resx file has:

```
<data name="lblTeamResource1.ToolTip" xml:space="preserve">
    <value />
</data>
<data name="lblTeamResource1.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Team:</value>
</data>
```

When inspecting the element it produces

```
<span id="manager_lblTeam" title="

">
Team2:
</span>
```

If I query the resource value in VS Immediate Window, it has \n before and after the value. If I change the xml:space to "default", it doesn't add the new lines.

So my question is how do I stop it from adding the new lines without changing every xml:space="preserve" to "default"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see two options (if you don't want to remove "preserve")
- modify the input
- modify the output

But I think the easiest way would be to simply delete it altogether... You obviously don't want the behavior of "preserve" setting.